# Angabe und Ergänzungen

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, adverb

Die Regel lautet, dass eine Dativ-Ergänzung vor/nach einer temporalen Angabe stehen soll und Akkusativ-Ergänzungen vor einer lokalen Angabe. Wenn ich das richtig verstehe, gilt die Regel nur für die Sätze, die mehrere Angaben haben. Wenn es  nur eine Angabe gibt, dann stehen die Ergänzungen vor der Angabe

Z.B. Ich habe **sie(Akk.) ihm(Dat.) erst gestern (temp.)** vorgestellt.

Ich habe **ihm (Dat.) gestern (temp.) wegen eines Projektes (Kaus.) endlich (mod.) sie (Akk.) bei mir zu Hause (Lok.)** vorgestellt.

Habe ich das richtig verstanden?

Comment: Eine Regel, die besagt, dass Dativ **vor/nach** einer temporalen Angabe steht, ist ziemlich sinnlos, weil sie damit alles erlaubt.

Answer (score 1):

Grundsätzlich gibt es nur wenige "Regeln", das meiste sind Tendenzen. Im Deutschen ist die Satzstellung sehr flexibel, jedoch nicht beliebig frei. Daher ist es schier unmöglich, alles in Regeln zu fassen.

Die Regel, auf die du dich bezogen hast, gilt erstmal, wenn die Objekte keine Pronomen sind. Ich ersetze daher die Pronomen erstmal durch konkrete Personen.

Auf Subjekt, Prädikat und Objekte vereinfacht lautet der Satz:

> Ich habe meinem Vater meine Freundin vorgestellt.

Die einzige "Regel", die hier angewandt wird, ist die V2-Regel für das finite Verb. Der Satz ist in der Form S-P-O, und die Pronomen werden nach der Tendenz "Dativobjekt vor Akkusativobjekt" positioniert.

Unabhängig davon, welches Adverb, Präpositionalphrase etc. du nun in den Satz einfügst, das Natürlichste ist, dies zwischen den Objekten einzufügen.

> Ich habe meinem Vater gestern meine Freundin vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe meinem Vater endlich meine Freundin vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe meinem Vater wegen eines Projektes meine Freundin vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe meinem Vater bei mir zu Hause meine Freundin vorgestellt.

Alternativ könntest du diese an den Anfang setzen. Dann würde das Subjekt zwischen finites Verb und Dativobjekt gesetzt.

> Gestern habe ich meinem Vater meine Freundin vorgestellt.

Wenn du nun zwei oder mehr hinzufügst, kommt die Frage auf, in welcher Reihenfolge. Diese lautet:

> Zeit vor Grund vor Ort vor Art und Weise

"Gestern" ist die Zeit, "wegen eines Projektes" der Grund, "bei mir zu Hause" der Ort. Bei "endlich" bin ich mir grad nicht sicher, was das nun wäre. Ich glaube, es kommt ans Ende.

> Ich habe meinem Vater gestern wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause endlich meine Freundin vorgestellt.

Möchtest du eines betonen, kannst du dieses an den Satzanfang verschieben. Das Natürlichste ist, wirklich nur eines nach vorne zu ziehen. Aber angenommen, dass du nun Ort und Zeit betonen willst, kannst du auch Folgendes sagen:

> Gestern bei mir zu Hause habe ich meinem Vater wegen eines Projektes endlich meine Freundin vorgestellt.

Der ein oder andere wird bis hierher schon viele "Fehler" in meiner Antwort gefunden habe. Der Grund ist, dass all diese Tendenzen mehr oder weniger stark sind. Dadurch sind Verschiebungen der einzelnen Wörter/Phrasen nur allzu legitim und der Satz kann durchaus anders aufgebaut werden. Ich habe lediglich die "natürlichste" Form beschrieben.

Vor allen Dingen die Tendenz "Dativobjekt vor Akkusativobjekt" greift nicht mehr, wenn Pronomen ins Spiel kommen. Das Akkusativobjekt rutscht nach vorne, wenn es ein Pronomen ist.

> Ich habe ihm gestern meine Freundin vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe sie meinem Vater gestern vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe sie ihm gestern vorgestellt.

Das Beste ist, wenn du dich anfangs an diese Tendenzen hältst. Je mehr du von diesen abweichst, desto wahrscheinlicher ist es, dass du einen Satz bildest, der eben schräg klingt. Mit der Zeit wirst du dann lernen, was sonst noch machbar ist (und da ist so einiges!) und was man lassen sollte.

Letztlich sei noch erwähnt, dass es auch noch "gebundene Adverbialbestimmungen" gibt, die in dieser Antwort (und auch in deiner Frage) gänzlich fehlen.

Answer (score 1):

Versuche gar nicht erst, die Regel als »Regel« zu verstehen! Speichere sie als »Möglichkeit« ab. Im Deutschen ist die Wortstellung weitgehend frei, solange das Verb an zweiter Stelle steht (und Verbergänzungen, wie Infinitivkonstruktionen, Partizipien bei Passiv/Perfekt oder abgetrennte Teile trennbarer Verben an letzter Stelle). Der einzige Unterschied ist, dass anderer Wortreihenfolgen mehr Spannung in den Satz bringen. (Spannung nicht wie »spannender Film«, sondern »nach ›fest‹ kommt ›ab‹«.)

> Erst gestern habe ich sie ihm vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe erst gestern sie ihm vorgestellt.
>   Ihm habe ich sie erst gestern vorgestellt.

Eine nichtabschließende Liste von Möglichkeiten für deinen ersten Beispielsatz. Deine Version passt auch noch dazu; damit hätten wir jede mögliche Reihenfolge von Dativ, Akkusativ und Temporaladverbial gehabt. Und auch aus dem zweiten Beispiel lassen sich einige Permutationen bauen:

> Ich habe sie ihm gestern wegen eines Projekts bei mir zuhause endlich vorgestellt.
>   Ich habe ihm wegen eines Projekts bei mir zuhause gestern endlich sie vorgestellt.
>   Wegen eines Projekts bei mir zuhause habe ich sie ihm gestern endlich vorgestellt.

Auch hier bin ich wieder zu faul, alle 6! = 720 möglichen Permutationen hinzuschreiben und nach weniger oder mehr eingeführter Spannung zu beurteilen. Mit der Zeit wirst du mitbekommen, welche Ordnung mehr und welche weniger Spannung induziert. Das hängt nicht nur von der syntaktischen Funktion der Wörter ab, sondern auch von ihrer Länge, ihrer Beziehung zueinander und wie wichtig sie für den Zusammenhang sind. Bei mehr als vier Gliedern haben sicher auch die Positionen von Jupiter und Merkur einen Einfluss.

Answer (score 0):

Jein. Es gibt im Deutschen keine Regel wie die Satzglieder zu stehen haben.

Der erste Satz in der Frage ist genauso richtig wie

> Ich habe ihm (Dat.) sie (Akk.) erst gestern (temp.) vorgestellt.

und

> Ich habe erst gestern (temp.) ihm (Dat.) sie (Akk.) vorgestellt.

Bei diesen Sätzen wird jedoch ein Teil besonders betont.

Der zweite Beispielsatz ist etwas schwierig zu verstehen. Eine Formulierung wie diese ist häufiger.

> Wegen eines Projektes habe ich sie ihm gestern bei mir zu Hause endlich vorgestellt.

Ich glaube nicht, dass sich dafür eine genaue Regel formulieren lässt. Auch hier hat die Stellung nämlich wieder sehr viel mit der Betonung zu tun. Hat sie ihn endlich kennen gelernt oder hat er sie endlich kennen gelernt? Für mich klingt es als hat *er* sie endlich kennen gelernt, da sie ihm ja vorgestellt wurde, er wartete darauf. Das zweite Objekt ist meiner Meinung nach betonter, deshalb *ihm* als zweites. Grundsätzlich ist aber Akkusativ vor Dativ auch das üblichste.

Zeit und Ortsangaben kommen, wenn keine besondere Betonung darauf liegt, eher ans Ende. Würde in diesem Fall „bei mir zu Hause“ auf „endlich“ folgen, könnte der Satz so verstanden werden, dass der Sprecher sie ihm *bei sich zu Hause* vorstellen wollte und das nun endlich geschafft hat.

Begründungen kommen häufig an den Anfang: Man will den Zuhörer von voreiligen Schlüssen abhalten. „Wegen eines Projektes“ könnte aber auch genau so gut ohne Bedeutungsunterschied vor „endlich“ kommen.

Comment: Hm, aber warum im ersten Satz Dativ vor Akkusativ, obwohl OP Akk vor Dativ hatte, was natürlicher ist. (Stichwort: Tendenzen / beide Objekte Pronomen)

Comment: @Em1 Ich wollte nur zeigen, dass die Satzglieder fast beliebig angeordnet werden können, war eigentlich nicht als Empfehlung gedacht. Habe die Antwort bearbeitet um das klarzustellen.

Comment: Ja.... Akkusativ vor Dativ ist das üblichere, wenn, wie in diesem Fall, es sich um Pronomen handelt. Vor allen Dingen, wenn das Akk-Objekt ein Pronomen ist. Ersetze mal das Akk-Obj durch bspw. "eine Freundin" (unbestimmter Artikel). Wo würdest du es hinsetzen? – Die Regel, auf die OP sich im ersten Satz seiner Frage bezieht, setzt übrigens voraus, dass keine Pronomen im Spiel sind.

Comment: Das "Problem" ist, dass es zu dem Satz ca. 100 Möglichkeiten gibt. Diese sind mehr oder weniger natürlich, aber alle machbar. In einer Klausur hingegen würden nur einige wenige als korrekt angesehen. Eine Antwort sollte hier das Ziel haben, die "richtigen" Varianten hervorzuheben und nicht irgendwelche beliebige umgangssprachlich akzeptablen Alternativen.

Comment: @Em1 Ich weiß nicht wo ich "umgangssprachlich akzeptablen Alternativen Varianten hervorgehoben" habe. Diese Sätze mögen zwar ungewöhnlich sein, das Grammatikwerk aber, das diese verbietet habe ich bis jetzt noch nicht gesehen. Auch habe ich diese nicht empfohlen. (Und im Übrigen sind es nur 24 Möglichkeiten.)

Comment: Ich sehe auch kein Problem "Ich habe ihm eine Freundin erst gestern vorgestellt." zu sagen. ("Ich stellte ihm alle Freunde bis auf einige wenige vor. Ich habe ihm eine Freundin erst gestern vorgestellt.")

Answer (score 0):

> Ich habe ihm wegen eines Projektes endlich sie bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.

Diese Wortstellung ist so ungewöhnlich, dass ich sie in moderner Prosa schon als falsch empfinde. Selbst in alten Texten oder sehr poetischen Texten wäre sie ungewöhnlich. In den folgenden Beispielen lasse ich die Wörter *gestern* und *endlich* weg, weil sie für die Betrachtung nicht wichtig sind und es sehr viele Möglichkeiten gibt, sie unterzubringen.

**Normale Wortstellung:**

> 1. Ich habe sie ihm wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe sie ihm bei mir zu Hause wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt.

1 ist mehrdeutig. Vielleicht habe ich sie zu Hause vorgestellt und das Projekt findet anderswo statt. Oder vielleicht habe ich sie woanders vorgestellt und das Projekt findet bei mir zu Hause statt. Dagegen legt sich 2 fest: Die Vorstellung fand zu Hause statt; zum Ort des Projekts gibt es keine Aussage.

**Besondere Wortstellungen(*sie* und *ihm* vertauscht)**

> 1. Ich habe ihm sie wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe ihm sie bei mir zu Hause wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt.

Er steht momentan im Fokus der Geschichte, und ich möchte, dass das so bleibt. Evt. ist es auch nicht selbstverständlich, dass ich gerade sie ihm vorgestellt habe, und nicht jemand anders. Ansonsten wie bei der normalen Wortstellung.

**Besondere Wortstellungen (*sie* an anderer Stelle):**

> 1. Sie habe ich ihm wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.
> 2. Sie habe ich ihm bei mir zu Hause wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt.

Wie vorher, aber mit starker Betonung auf *sie*. (Weil das konjugierte Verb (*habe*) an zweiter Stelle bleiben muss, ist *ich* weiter nach hinten gerutscht.)

> 1. Ich habe ihm wegen eines Projektes sie bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe ihm bei mir zu Hause sie wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt.

1 Dass ich sie ihm bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt habe, setze ich als bekannt voraus. Neu ist nur der Grund: wegen eines Projektes. 2 Dass ich sie ihm wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt habe, setze ich als bekannt voraus. Neu ist nur der Ort der Vorstellung: bei mir zu Hause.

Der Fokus der Erzählung liegt bisher, und bleibt, auf *ihm*.

> 1. Ich habe ihm wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause sie vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe ihm bei mir zu Hause wegen eines Projektes sie vorgestellt.

Ergibt in der modernen Umgangssprache gar keinen Sinn, da überhaupt nicht klar ist, welche Nuance hier ausgedrückt werden soll. So etwas kommt in poetischer Sprache trotzdem gelegentlich vor, z.B. um ein bestimmtes Versmaß zu erzwingen. Das gibt es ganz ähnlich auch im Englischen.

**Besondere Wortstellungen (*ihm* an anderer Stelle):**

> 1. Ihm habe ich sie wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.
> 2. Ihm habe ich sie bei mir zu Hause wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt.

Wie vorher, aber mit starker Betonung auf *ihm*. (Weil das konjugierte Verb (*habe*) an zweiter Stelle bleiben muss, ist *ich* weiter nach hinten gerutscht.)

> 1. Ich habe sie wegen eines Projektes ihm bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe sie bei mir zu Hause ihm wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt.

1 Dass ich sie ihm bei mir zu Hause vorgestellt habe, setze ich als bekannt voraus. Neu ist nur der Grund: wegen eines Projektes. 2 Dass ich sie ihm wegen eines Projektes vorgestellt habe, setze ich als bekannt voraus. Neu ist nur der Ort der Vorstellung: bei mir zu Hause.

Der Fokus der Erzählung liegt bisher, und bleibt, auf *sie*.

> 1. Ich habe sie wegen eines Projektes bei mir zu Hause ihm vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe sie bei mir zu Hause wegen eines Projektes ihm vorgestellt.

Für 2 gilt das früher über ähnliche Varianten Gesagte bzgl. Verwendung nur in poetischer Sprache. 1 löst das Problem der Mehrdeutigkeit des ursprünglichen Satzes 1 in der entgegengesetzten Richtung wie der ursprüngliche Satz 2 auf: Das Projekt fand dei mir zu Hause statt, über den Ort der Vorstellung ist keine Aussage getroffen.

**Weitere Wortstellungen**

An dieser Stelle sollte klar sein, dass es noch weitere Varianten gibt, in denen sowohl *sie* als auch *ihm* an ungewöhnlichen Stellen stehen. Hier nur ein Beispiel:

> 1. Ich habe wegen eines Projektes sie bei mir zu Hause ihm vorgestellt.
> 2. Ich habe bei mir zu Hause sie wegen eines Projektes ihm vorgestellt.

Höchstens in poetischer Sprache zu erwarten, obwohl man hier auch Betonungen und Fokus hineinlesen kann.

Aus den gebräuchlicheren oben beschriebenen Varianten kann man allerdings manchmal neue gewinnen, indem man *sie* oder *ihm* an den Anfang des Satzes verschiebt, um es zu betonen.

**Schlussbemerkung**

Das Englische kommt ohne die flexible Wortstellung aus, einfach nur durch Betonung und Satzmelodie. Das funktioniert im Deutschen auch: Es geht immer auch mit der normalen Wortstellung. Je länger und komplizierter ein Satz ist, umso wichtiger ist es, der normalen Wortstellung zu folgen.

Im Extremfall von ganz kurzen Sätzen gibt es ansatzweise freie Wortstellung sogar noch im Englischen, oder gab es sie zumindest bis vor relativ kurzer Zeit noch. (Sicher in einigen Dialekten noch heute.) Beispiel: "I gave it her. I gave her it. Her I gave it. It I gave her." Wie man am Deutschen sehen kann, begann die Standardisierung der Wortstellung wohl mit langen Sätzen.

PS: Ein grundsätzlicher Unterschied zwischen einer Ergänzung und mehreren ist mir nicht bekannt. Vielleicht sollte ja nur ausgedrückt werden, dass direktes und/oder indirektes Objekt im Fall von mehreren Ergänzungen sogar zwischen den Ergänzungen stehen können. *Können*! Die normale Wortstellung ist das nicht.